# When I change the background of my UIButton it resizes

Tags: ios6, xcode4, uibutton

I am looking to change my UIButton background image using a click event but when I do the buttons resize, what can I do to prevent this? The code I'm using is below.

```
UIImage *btnImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Bttn_DateSel_Up.png"];
[startDtSelBttn setImage:btnImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
UIImage *btnImage2 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Bttn_DateSel_Down_Clear.png"];
[endDtSelBttn setImage:btnImage2 forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Comment: Please post the code where you handle click events; otherwise it's difficult to understand what the actual problem is.

Comment: For which button you faced the problem. And please also explain what you want ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this would help you:

```
-(IBAction)btnClicked:(id)sender
{
  [startDtSelBttn setImage:SomeOtherButtonImageNameHere forState:UIControlStateNormal]
}
```

This will change the image of the button `startDtSelBttn`.

Also, if you want your button to have two images one for normal state and one for selected image, then you can write your code like this:

```
UIImage *btnImageNormal   = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Bttn_DateSel_Up.png"];
UIImage *btnImageSelected = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Bttn_DateSel_Up_Selected.png"];
[startDtSelBttn setImage:btnImageNormal forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[startDtSelBttn setImage:btnImageSelected forState:UIControlStateSelected];
```

Hope it will help you.